# Laravel 5.5 CRFS Token Expires

Tags: session, laravel-5

I am developing an application that basically consist in only one frontend form (with an only one autosubmit text field), that must shows itself at least for 24hs. It's like a Kiosk application frontend. 
Everything works fine, but in the middle of testing process i noticed that CRFS token expires and crash my application, so my doubt is if exits any way to set the token ttl to "X" minutes or with a simply browser refresh will be enough.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your .env add

```
SESSION_LIFETIME=1440
```

(Set session life to 1440 mins)

Comment: Hi! thanks for your reply, i already did it, but did no work.... do you have any idea for what?

Comment: It could be hard set by php setting.